# How to convert Data Table to Binary Byte Array with Field Codes C#

Tags: c#

So i'm trying to convert this Data Table into a binary byte array using field codes. Basically I'm trying to encrypt the data using the data table as input so I need something that will be "soft" so it doesn't matter what the data table is, i'll be able to convert it. I'm extremely new to C# so i apologize in advance if I'm overlooking something simple, just trying to help out a friend.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data;

namespace DataTableConversion
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test")) 
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Last Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("First Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Cellphone", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
            dt.Columns.Add("Credit Card #", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Amount Entered", typeof(double));
            dt.Rows.Add("Lawson", "Adam", "7572773709", DateTime.Now, "4000848093", "75.00");

            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Last Name = {0}, First Name = {1}, Cellphone = {2}, Date = {3}, Credit Card = {4}, Amount Entered = {5}", dr["Last Name"], dr["First Name"], dr["Cellphone"], dr["Date"], dr["Credit Card #"], dr["Amount Entered"]);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868156/encrypt-column-data-with-linq

Comment: You say "encrypt". Do you want to just make it just unreadable to humans, or is really encryption a concern? Also is size a concern? If size is no matter, just serialize it via XML and then encrypt it and write it out to a binary array. That way serializing and de-serializing becomes very simple, because C# has a very robust and easy to use XML implementation.