# Encryption/Decryption on columns of already existing table in SQL Server 2008 with LinqToSql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, encryption, linq-to-sql

We have a table, say tbl_X, in our database. This table is in PROD for quite sometime and has approximately 2000 rows. Rows are updated and inserted into this table only once in a while. When this table was created, protection and security were not considered. However,this table consists of data which we think needs some level of protection.

We now want to encrypt the values of some of the columns in the table before saving anything. And we want to decrypt the value before displaying on UI(or before performing any other action).

So the scenario is:

DB server: SQL SERVER 2008

tbl_X Schema:

```
Id int not null,
Name varchar(100) not null,
CustAccount varchar(100) not null,
CustPrefText varchar(200) not null,
CreatedBy int not null
```

We want encryption on columns CustAccount and CustPrefText.

We use Linq2SQL to get and set the data in the table. So we are thinking of something achieving the said requirement like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868156/encrypt-column-data-with-linq):

```
public partial class tbl_X
{
    public string CustAccount
    {
        get
        {
            return Crypter.Decrypt(this.CustAccount)
        }
        set
        {
            this.CustAccount= Crypter.Encrypt(value)
        }
   }
}
```

Questions:

1. Is there any better way to handle the change?
2. Is there a possibility that the existing data in the table will cause any issues while manually updating them?
3. Will it be required to change the datatypes of the mentioned columns?

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: Why don't you use SQL Server's own encryption ? That answers #1. For #2 - using custom encryption will probably result in *weaker* encryption. You won't be able to query the data without your class either. #3. What *does* your `Crypter.Encrypt` return? Isn't it string? How long is it?

Comment: We are using LinqToSql. How do I ensure that what I am reading from the table is decrypted?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: We have used LinqToSql in the entire project, but to use SQL Server's own encryption, we would have to write Stored procs to read and write, which we don't want. Could you point me towards some material i could read from ?

Answer (score 1):

AlwaysEncrypted is what you need. It is a client side encryption technology, and will work with ADO.Net SqlClient, and hence will also work with LinqToSql. Here are more details: [AlwaysEncrypted client development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt147923.aspx)

However you will need SQL server 2016 for this.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to do this with SQL Server 2008. Any suggestions there?

Comment: I guess you will have to stick with the approach you've shown. You may need to change data types based on what your encryption function returns. Since you seem to be encrypting only varchar columns you might not need to change data type, but not sure about the size.

Comment: If I use my way, could you please suggest any function that I might use to encrypt/decrypt on the c# side. I want a c# function whose equivalent is available in sql also, so that I can query the table manually through SSMS when needed.

Comment: I'm afraid there are no such libraries that are available, AFAIK. You can try using standard encryption algorithms which have an equivalent in both c# and SQL. But philosophically speaking, that defeats the purpose of encryption in the first place. The point of encryption is to ensure nobody else can make sense of the data even if they could get into your database.